# Issue with multiple barcode detection with Zbar Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, barcode-scanner, zbar

I'm trying to use pyzbar for an auto barcode checking project. The goal is to detect info and type for every each barcode from an artwork sheet with multiple barcodes.

The code below works fine for one barcode or a couple different ones. But in my case, there are 20 in total of 4 different barcodes. The result only gives back 4 different codes and 4 coordinates. It looks like zbar skipped all the repeated barcodes. The marking boxes look weird as well. Any ideas why?

*2408 3468 2966 107*

*0690461219945EAN13*

*278 3468 2287 107*

*0690461219952EAN13*

*278 1529 2434 107*

*0990461219816EAN13*

*435 1529 4939 1939*

*0690461219990EAN13*

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("test-1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t,bimage = cv2.threshold(gray,160,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


barcodes = pyzbar.decode(bimage)


for barcode in barcodes:
    (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect

    print(x,y,w,h)

    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), thickness=2)

    barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
    barcodeType = barcode.type
    print (barcodeData+barcodeType)

    text = "{} ({})".format(barcodeData, barcodeType)
    cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite("test1_re.png", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Test Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvwlL.png)

[Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJgjn.png)

Comment: did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I ended up using opencv to segment each barcode and then decode each of them, instead of passing the whole image to zbar.